# Does fanatic badge counts access from the app?

Tags: support, badges

From the help page:

> Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.).

So, does access from the stack exchange app counts as visiting the site?

Comment: (Converted to answer)

Comment: Nice, I guess that answer the question. Do you know if what is considered "real" access is already defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/145982) from a developer. [This other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/145982) defines "real" access as access to non-"homepage style" pages. I know the login page and the question list don't count as real, but viewing any individual question does

Comment: FWIW, I believe that accessing [the review page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review) *does* count as a real access.  Also your user page.  Also note that consecutive days of visitation (for purposes of awarding the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges) are counted independently, not just for each community, but for the main and meta sites within each community.